# SVG image not showing in simple android cordova table

Tags: android, cordova, svg

In a fairly simple table i'm filling the rows dynamic based on some json feedback. The problem is when I use png files nothing seems to be out of order but when I use svg images they seem to be transparent. When I open these images in a browser they are just fine. To be clear this is an android app running on a S8 build with cordova 9

I've looked on the web for solution (stackoverflow, cordova) but nothing seems conclusive. Examples/answers given were tried but did not come to a solutin. The console inspector (chrome) is not reporting any missing files or script errors

html/javascript call function

```
var imgNode = document.getElementById('fractieimg');
if (imgNode != null) {
imgNode.setAttribute("src", "img/" + getStroomImage(fractie.stromen));
        }
```

Result HTML

```
<li class="fractierow" id="frow" onclick="selectFractie('REST');">
     <div class="fractieimg">
     <img width="35" id="fractieimg" src="img/svg/cal_rest.svg"></div>
     <div class="fractienaam" id="fractienaam">REST</div>
     <img class="fractienext" id="next" width="13" src="img/icon_next_groen.png"></li>
```

javascript

```
function getStroomImage(stroom) {
if (stroom == "REST") return "svg/cal_rest.svg";    }
```

I would expect the image cal_rest.svg to appear at the starting line from the row. But only the text 'REST' appears and the icon_next_groen.png appears

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Android is not supporting SVG try to convert it to XML asset.

you can try to conver it here [Asset studio](https://inloop.github.io/svg2android/)k-end

or use Android Studio built in tool.

another option is to do conversation in back-end and return .png

Comment: Why, why are things never straight forward out-of-the-box? Thank you for your response. Appreciate the answer, voted for correct but to i'm a newbie

Comment: SVGs work perfectly on Android, your issue has nothing to do with SVGs